# Thymeleaf onclick attribute with JS script won't work in Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, function, thymeleaf

I have a table generated through:

`<tr *some other th tags* th:onclick="'javascript:openPoolModal(\''+ ${networkHashrate.id} + '\');'">`

I have a `openPoolModal` function in `static/js/openPoolModal.js`

I have added a `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/openPoolModal.js"></script>` to the `.html` file header where the function is used.

The function looks like this:

```
function openPoolModal(id){

$.ajax({
    url: "/" + id,
    success: function(data){
    $("#PoolModalHolder").html(data);
    $("#PoolModal").modal("show");
    }
});
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error? What have you tried to fix it? What is the result?

Comment: There's no error. It seems that the script just does not work, cause clicking does literally nothing. I've tried to correct scripts paths, didn't work.

Comment: A table is properly generated, with correct data. Clicking the rows does nothing, but it should trigger the JS function.

Comment: Is that function being called? Before you start your ajax did you `console.log(id);` to see what's being passed, if the function is called, etc?

Comment: Just checked with `console.log`. Apparently, it wasn't called.

Comment: Is your html file in the same `/static` directory?

Comment: If you move your `function openPoolModal(id)` to your html file is it called then?

Comment: No. It's under `resources/templates` directory.

Comment: I did `<tr *other th tags* onclick="openPoolModal()">` and pasted the script below. Now I'm getting `
2018-04-10 15:20:58.721 ERROR 2656 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"] with root cause
`

Comment: Okay, then this problem is solved. You're not calling your javascript function from that file. I suspect it's your script tag that's not pointing to the correct directory / file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a directory problem. You're including the js file by calling this script from your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/openPoolModal.js"></script>
```

But if your html file is in directory `resources/templates/` then this script is trying to call `resources/js/openPoolModel.js` which isn't where your Javascript file is.

Adding the js function directly to the html file called the function so your script and directory is wrong.